# Intuition for Kozsul algebras/Lie algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, free-lie-algebra

What is the intuition behind Koszul graded-commutative algebras and Lie algebras? Why is it an interesting property to study in commutative algebra? I know why it's interesting in homotopy theory but what about in algebraic geometry or commutative algebra?

Comment: Your terminology is a little ambiguous; there is something called a Koszul algebra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koszul_algebra) but your use of "Koszul commutative" makes it sound like you might be referring to *graded*-commutative algebras and Lie algebras?

Comment: I'm asking about graded or ungraded commutative algebras and Lie algebras which are Koszul.

Comment: We can view ungraded things (vector space, modules, algebras) as graded things concentrated in degree zero. Could you please be more specific on what is ambiguous?